# How to determine optimal settings for a Synaptic touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I'm using Q4OS on a netbook and so far the experience has been rather pleasant, except that the touchpad is not working anywhere near close to optimal.  Experiences with Ubuntu/Lubuntu, Manjaro Cinnamon, OpenSUSE, and a few other distros have yielded similar experiences as well unfortunately (even though the graphical config tools have helped slightly).

The biggest problem has been that of palm detection.  The second biggest problem has been sensitivity.  I noticed [this post](http://stevenkohlmeyer.com/fixing-palm-detect-ubuntu-14-04/) and was very hopeful that this would help resolve the issue, but some parts were left out such as determining the actual pad size.

How does one determine optimal dimensions and settings for a trackpad / touchpad / clickpad such as the Synaptic on an HP Stream 13? (Synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf00123/0x840300/0x12e800, board id: 3003, fw id: 1738305)

Also, is there some general GUI that could be installed that would help determine and test settings more quickly than using `synclient` directly?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't say anything about palm detection and sensitivity, with `wayland/libinput`, coordinate ranges (read "dimensions") can be tuned via `touchpad-edge-detector` (distributed with `libevdev` on Gentoo/Funtoo) as [explained here](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.7.0/absolute_coordinate_ranges.html).